# If loop does not take correct judgement based on variable type

Tags: python, python-3.x, if-statement

In the code below, if loop does not take the condition (of true) and instead goes to the `elif` statement. I am trying to use `if` statement to control what could go into a list and what can not :

```
average = []

def judge(result):
    try:
        float(result)
        return True
    except ValueError:
        return 'please type number'

list_in = input('Type in your number,type y when finished.\n')
judge_result = judge(list_in)
if judge_result:
    aver_trac = aver_trac + 1
    average.append(list_in)
    print('success')
elif isinstance(judge_result, str):
    print(judge_result)
```

However if I specify

```
if judge_result == True:
```

then this if loop will work

Comment: Due to implicit booleaness python will evaluate 'please type number' as True. Try `bool('please type number')`

Comment: non-empty strings are Truthy.

Comment: You should be returning `True` or `False` from your `judge()` function, then testing that in the calling code to decide whether to print an error message or not. Separate your concerns!

Comment: If statements don't loop

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Python evaluates non empty strings as True, and empty strings as False.

In your case, the `judge` function returns either `True`, or a non empty string, which is also True; When you evaluate the return, `if judge_result:` is always True.

The fact that `if judge_result == True:` works, is a great example of the difference between `==` and `is` in python

with all that said, the way you approach the input of your data is a bit awkward; you could do something like this instead:

```
average = []


while True:
    list_in = input('Type in your number,type y when finished.\n')
    if list_in == 'y':
        break
    try:
        average.append(float(list_in))
    except ValueError:
        print('please type number')
```

Comment: Thanks! I used a different ways to check the input based on the returned value, however it is really bulky compared to this one.